# Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue()

Tags: php, date, zend-framework

I am trying to create a new filter for date selection that is this:

```
$startAutocomplete = $toolbar->addInput($translator->translate('Nga'), 'start_date', 'start_date');

$startAutocomplete = $toolbar->setScript('
    var dates = $("#start_date").button({}).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "%%",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: -600,
        maxDate: "+12M",
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            var option = this.id == "start_date" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
            instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                selectedDate, instance.settings
            );
            dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
        }
    });
');
```

and I want this date to be used as a report parameter using

```
$params.="&start_date=". $startAutocomplete->getValue();
```

but I get a fatal error. I think I have to convert the date or something.

Comment: Anyone? No answer? :s

Answer (score 0):

$startAutocomplete is probably correct when it calls addInput but when it calls setScript you are appear to be redefining $startAutocomplete to be null or something else which triggers your error.

Change this:

```
$startAutocomplete = $toolbar->setScript(...)
```

To this:

```
$toolbar->setScript(...)
```

If I'm incorrect then we'll need you post you to post more information of your code but based on what you provided this looks to be the cause.

Comment: I actually solved it. The problem was when i wanted to get the values so i changed it to this and worked fine
`$params.="&start_date=".$args['from'];`